# Rails HTTParty same 404 response in 2 different APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404, httparty

My Rails app just started to return 404 errors last Thursday on our `Staging` server, and I'm trying to figure out why. We hit 2 completely different APIs in our app, and they have been working for months. All of a sudden, we got 404 errors all morning, and without any changes, they work again.

We are using [`HTTParty`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to hit these external APIs. The response for both APIs are **exactly** the same, and it is a generic html template for 404 errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My initial guess is that we somehow hit the wrong endpoint for both, which is unlikely because we never changed anything and they have been working for months. But I tried to hit the wrong endpoint in one of the external API anyway, and this is the response I got:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor=\"white\">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed right away that these two 404 html templates are different, and at this point, I'm not sure what really happened. Since we got the same exact 404 response for both APIs, my hunch is that something is wrong on our side, not theirs, but I'm not 100% sure. I would really appreciate any help! Thanks!